# My equation is not showing big bracket and not showing in next line

Tags: equations

```
\begin{equation}
g(f,t) = \begin{cases}
         \bigl{b^Nt^N^-^1e^2^\pi^b^t cos(2\pi ft),  \text{t\geq 0;}\\
         0 \text{ $ otherwise $}
         \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please post a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. You are doing many mistakes here. `\bigl{` should be `\bigl\{` (but is it needed), the first `\text` needs math mode inside it (the contents is math, the other one does not (its text) and you need ``\\`` to break the line inside cases env

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Your code has to much errors  to be useful (see *daleif* comment). Please provide image of it written by hand.

Comment: The string `b^Nt^N^-^1e^2^\pi^b^t` cannot possibly be correct. Please edit and fix your code.

Answer (score 7):

I think that you mean something like this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
g(f,t) = \begin{cases}
           b^Nt^{N^{-1}}e^{2\pi b^t}\cos(2\pi ft),&  \text{if }t\geq 0,\\
           0,& \text{otherwise.}
         \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Note, in particular:

- you don't need to add `\bigl\{` because part of the point of the the `cases` environment is that it adds the large left brace around the equations for you
- use `&` to separate the branches of the functions and the text that describes them
- to create superscripts use brackets to group the elements in the exponent: so `e^{2\pi t}` is, mathematically, the same as `\exp(2\pi t)`
- use `\text{...}` to print text inside equations. In particular, gets you out of math-mode...your expression `\text{ $ otherwise $}` is wrong in so many ways: `\text{otherwise}` is what you want, Also, be careful with spaces because `\text{ otherwise }` will print `otherwise`
- if you want to type braces in LaTeX then you need to use `\{` and `\}`, rather than `{` and `}`
- many standard functions like cos, sin, exp, ... have their own macros: `\cos`, `\sin`, `\exp`, .... It looks much better if you use these because, otherwise, TeX will typeset `cos` etc so that it looks like `c*o*s`

Comment: I'd probably use `\text{if $t\geq0$},` just because the entire text is the comment. Better semantics

Comment: @daleif Yes, I agree/ In this case it isn't so clear but if the condition was `\text{if $t\ge0$ and $f<0$},` it your approach is definitely better. This said, I normally use `\begin{cases*}...\end{cases*}` from [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), which does this implicitly, but I didn't want to mention this here because the OP has enough other things to worry about.

Comment: Please, fix the cosine

Comment: it also can be (more probably) `g(f,t) = \begin{cases}
           b^N t^{N-1}\mathrm{e}^{2\pi b t} \cos(2\pi f t), &  \text{if }t\geq 0,\\
           0, & \text{otherwise.}
         \end{cases}` :)